# Github desktop - как работать с чужими репозиториями?

Tags: github

Привет, сейчас пользуюсь оболочкой Source Tree, репозиторий лежит на github, владельцу дал SSH ключ, и вобщем  нет никаких проблем с использованием, но сегодня решил использовать родной клиент Github Desktop, мои репозитории он видит, и синхронизирует хорошо, а вот те репозитории что созданы не моим аккаунтом - не хочет с ними работать, он их видет, делает коммиты, но не синхронизирует.

> The repository doesn't seem to exist anymore/ You may not have access or it may have been deleted or renamed

Он даже не просит SSH авторизации, просто тупо не синхронизирует[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я бы попробовал в консоле для начала. С гитхабовской приблуды можно открыть git console. И вот там для начала попробовать сделать git pull (в гите нет понятия синхронизации, а гитхаб выдумал ее для комбинации pull/push)